# PDE Calculus 3 information

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I must compute   $ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}  $ of the following expression
$$ z^2 e^{2x} = 3z + x\ln (y) $$

I know how to compute partial derivatives in general , though I'm not sure what to do in this problem , generally what we've covered in class are expressions of the form 
$$ z = (\dots) $$ then we were asked to compute $ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}  $ or $ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}  $

So from my understanding , I must regroup the $z$ values on one side of the equation and the other variables on the other side , then apply the formulae. Although, I can't seem to do that in this problem ; Attempt :

$$ \frac{x\ln(y)}{e^{2x}-\dfrac{3}{z}}= z^2$$

Also does anyone know what's the command for tilted fractions in MathJax ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you 'must regroup the z values on one side of the equation'. You don't have to group things in any particular way. You just need to apply the product rule and chain rule.

Comment: thank you for your comment, do I have to apply $ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}  $ on both sides of the equation ?

Comment: You have to apply $\partial/\partial x$ to both sides. _'What you do to one side you have to do to the other'_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take implicit derivative of the both sides $ z^2 e^{2x} = 3z + x\ln y $ to get

$$2z\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}e^{2x} +z^2 2e^{2x}=3\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+ \ln y$$

Thus,

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\ln y - 2z^2 e^{2x} }{2ze^{2x} -3}$$

Similarly,

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{x}{y(2ze^{2x} -3)}$$

Answer (score 0):

If having all of the extra stuff on one side really concerns you, you could always rearrange your function like this:

$z = \sqrt{\frac{3z + x \ln(y)}{e^{2x}}}$

Then differentiate with respect to $x$ and $y$.

Do any of [these tricks](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23283/slanted-fractions-in-mathjax) seem to help you with MathJax?

Here are the solutions both with respect to $x$ and $y$, so you can check your work:
[image]
[image]

Comment: But all of the extra stuff _isn't_ on one side.